# How to trick the "device fingerprint" on browser

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, browser, private-browsing

My question is about a site that give you a sign up bonus and this bonus is given once per PC ("machine id,ip adress etc...")

My purpose is to bypass this gate to create more accounts from the same pc and my question is how to do this.

I have search on internet about this topic and found that the thing that makes my pc unique on internet browsing is the 'device fingerprint'.

To bypass this I thought that use Wmware and create a virtual machine (I saw that is has a different mac adress) and to change my ip just disconnect and connect the internet.
An other idea was to use a browser that allows you to navigate anonymously(like Tor browser).

Are OK my variants? If yes which one? If no one, please help me to figure out this (maybe even some advices)

Comment: This might break the TOS from the website. Therefore, most people here will not help.

Comment: @TheKB Any idea where I could try?

Comment: I **will not** help you violate the website's TOS.

Comment: @TheKB You have misunderstood, I referred to another website where may I ask

Comment: @Dragos: You don't indicate where you're located, but perhaps one like [this](http://www.cdcr.ca.gov/Facilities_Locator/SQ.html), perhaps even as a contributor.